# Scikit learn linear regression with several outputs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to use scikit learn to do linear regression with several outputs

code (random data as example):

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(300,10)
y = np.random.rand(300,9)
reg_model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg_model.fit(X,y)
```

I get the collowing error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/sorensonderby/Documents/workspaces/workspace/Chemoinformatics_proect/notebooks/<ipython-input-116-e235c7159573> in <module>()
      5 y = np.random.rand(300,9)
      6 reg_model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
----> 7 reg_model.fit(X,y)
      8 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.10-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/sklearn/linear_model/base.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    178                     linalg.lstsq(X, y)
    179 
--> 180         self._set_intercept(X_mean, y_mean, X_std)
    181         return self
    182 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.10-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/sklearn/linear_model/base.pyc in _set_intercept(self, X_mean, y_mean, X_std)
    106         """
    107         if self.fit_intercept:
--> 108             self.coef_ = self.coef_ / X_std
    109             self.intercept_ = y_mean - np.dot(X_mean, self.coef_.T)
    110         else:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,9) (10)
```

I read the api for the fit method which says that x should be n_sample x n_features and y should be n_sample x n_targets. 
[Link to fit method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using scikit-learn 0.10 with the documentation for 0.13.1. Upgrade your installation, then try again -- it should work.